# Change all http to https in mysql databse?

Tags: database, query, mysql, https

I am trying to change all images links from http to https, is it possible doing that on a batch query working on the whole database? How?

Moreover my provider made a mess adding an "s" to https getting useless and wrong "httpss" ! 
So I must revert them from httpss to https.

Please help, many thanks.

Comment: there exist this good tools which help too for transfering website with buggy plugins : https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

Comment: Yes, try the plugin, "unsecure content fixer" - great thing to do exactly that. Easy, no trouble.

Comment: The plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/ helps you, it have a option for doing exactly this.

Comment: With the WP CLI it's possible to find and replace database settings: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/

Answer (score 2):

I should think that you can use phpAdmin Find and Replace where you find "http://www.example.com" and replace with "https://www.example.com". This should handle all internal linking (if blog, then internal linking as well as images, etc.). It would not cover relative addressing like "//www.example.com". In the case of Wordpress, this would be done on the wp_posts table, post_content column.

Answer (score 2):

you could use https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB. This is a great tool to find and replace in db, you just need to copy the srdb folder to root of your site( where your wp-config.php is), then open it :

> yourdomain.com/srdb

and then find and replace the strings in your db

for replacing use like this

```
httpss: ==> https:              //for those which have ss
http:   ==> https:              // for new one
```

adding

> :

to your replace statement prevent mistake

Answer (score 1):

Do not change these URLs in database. The protocol part should be 'http'. When 'https' request is being made, then first four characters of the URL is replaced by 'https', automatically. If URL from database starts with 'https' then result will be 'httpss'!

Comment: I acknowledge your good advice, but it's very odd that some "want be" technicians from my provider told me the best way is working directly on the database! I cross my finger waiting them to repair that mess!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a very good search/replace plugin that I'm using last year - [Better Search Replace](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/)

It's working very good. Be sure you'll create the DataBase backup before. I never had problems with this plugin, but you have to be sure, you have the DataBase copy in any case.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing to that plugin, I'll keep in mind whenever I'll need it.